# windows phone autocompletebox

Tags: windows-phone-7

are there sample of autocompletetextbox with dropdown button also it change the text color of match char in the list?

Answer (score 1):

The [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/60291) contains an AutoCompleteBox.

There is a detailed guide to its use at http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/autocompletebox-for-wp7-in-depth

Comment: But when I used this control, it has a weird alignment and seletion problem if I have 2 or more AutoCompleteBox on same page. It also have a problem if it is inside the Scrollviewer control.